# Is there any way to assign Id's to paragraphs in Open XML SDK 2.5?

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm working on an application which has to create word documents with the use of `Office Open XML SDK 2.5`. The idea that I'm having now is that I will start from a template with an empty body (so I have all the namespaces etc. defined already), and add `Paragraphs`to it. If I need images I will add the `ImageParts` and try to give the `ImagePart` the Id present in the predefined paragraphpart which will contain the image. I will store the paragraphs as xml in a database, fetch the ones I need, fill in/modify some values if needed and insert them into my word document. But this is the tricky part, how can I easily insert them in a way so I don't have to query on their content to later on find one of the paragraphs? In other words, I need Id's. I have some options in mind:

1. For each possible paragraph I have, manually create a `SdtBlock`. This `SdtBlock` will have an Id which matches the Id of each paragraph in the database. This seems like a lot of manual work though, and I'd rather be able to create future word documents easier...
   **I chose this approach but I insert `Building Blocks` which can be stored in templates with a specific tagname.**
2. Create the paragraphs, copy the xml from the developer tool, and manually add a `ParagraphId`. This seems even more of a nightmare though, because for every future new paragraphs I will have to create new Id's etc. Also it would be impossible to insert tables as there is no way (afaik) to give those an Id.
3. Work with bookmarks to know where to insert the data. I don't really like this either as bookmarks are visible for everyone. I know I can replace them, but then I don't have any way to identify individual paragraphs later on.
4. **** my database and just add everything in the template :D Remove the paragraphs I don't need by deleting the bookmarks with their content. This idea seems the worst of all though as I don't want to depend on having a templatefile with all possible content per word-file I need to generate.

Anyone with experience in `OpenXml` who knows which approach would be the best? Maybe there is another approach which is better and I have completely overlooked? The ideal solution would be that I can add Ids in `Office Word` but that's a no-go as I haven't found anything to do that yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a few ideas about OpenXML, but I don't really understand, how exactly do you work with your templates and documents and my answer would highly depend on it. Do you need to open document in word having these ids? BTW, bookmarks can be hidden - just add underscore before name (you can do it only from code)

Comment: I want an empty body (= empty word template), and I add the paragraphs I need to them. The paragraphs I would get from the database. But the document will be made depending on which options the user picks. So if the options change, I want to be able to remove certain paragraphs for example, so I need Id's

Comment: Why can't you just use it like usual xml, add your own elements with id there, and override them from database? What is the reason that you need to keep it in strict OpenXML? I can see only one reason for that - you need to open it in Word, and Word, for sure, removes everything it can't understand. If you don't need to open in Word before document is ready - just use your own elements.

Comment: @AlexButenko Hadn't thought of that yet, first time I work with xml really. So I'd use my word template, assemble the paragraphs in an `XDocument` for example and then add the `XDocument` to my empty template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content Controls (std) were designed for this, although I'm not sure the designers ever contemplated "targeting" each and every paragraph in the document...

Back in the 2003/2007 days it was possible to add custom XML mark-up to a Word document, which would have been exactly what you're looking for. But Microsoft lost a patent court case around 2009 and had to pull the functionality. So content controls are really your only good choice.

Your approach could, possibly, be combined with the BuildingBlocks concept. BuildingBlocks are Word content stored in a Word template file as valid Word Open XML. They can be assigned to "galleries" and categorized. There is a Content Control of type BuildingBlock that can be associated with a specific Gallery and Category which might help you to a certain extent and would be an alternative to storing content in a database.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that :)

Comment: Been looking into it, and although a bit hard to work with, this was really what I'm looking for :) Now I've been able to copy the `docPartBody` into my `SdtContentBlock`, but this way I don't have the images. I can of course copy the images I need from the template package to my document, but is there any easier way? (I've seen `defaultPlaceHolder` in the xml etc, so maybe there's an easier way to do it in open xml sdk?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I did a small research, you can do it in strict OpenXML, but only before you open your file in Word. Word will remove everything it cannot read.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true)) {
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Ancestors().First()
       .SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute() {
           LocalName = "someIdName",
           Value = "111" });
}
```

Here, for example, I set attribute "someIdName", which doesn't exits in OpenXML, to some random element. You can set it anywhere and use it as id

Comment: That's the thing, I need to keep the `id` so I can edit/remove/whatever later. But +1 for the idea of assembling the document outside of Word, going to experiment with that

Comment: This is why I asked about this. It makes big difference.